# What is UserJourney/PreserveOriginalAssertion

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, identity-experience-framework

This element is part of multiple samples, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Yet it's not explained anywhere, and it's missing from [reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/userjourneys).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is explained in the [Azure B2C custom policy starterpack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/TrustFrameworkPolicy_0.3.0.0.xsd#L869).

> Claims are presented to the Relying Party Application in a token
> generated by CPIM. However, a Technical Policy may state, using a true
> or a false for this element, that the original assertion which was
> returned from the Claims Provider(s) must also be preserved so that if
> needed, it can be looked at by Relying Party for auditing or
> diagnostic purposes.